# SQL Server 2005 - FREETEXTTABLE ignoring single characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, freetexttable

I have an issue with a query I'm running. Basically it's a search on a table of books. This query below uses the `FREETEXTTABLE` command to rank the search for an author:

```
@author = 'lewis c s'

SELECT *
FROM tbl_products
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(tbl_products, [author], @author, LANGUAGE 'British English') AS key_tbl ON tbl_products.product_id = key_tbl.[key]
WHERE deleted = 0
ORDER BY key_tbl.[rank] DESC, author ASC, title ASC, stl_product_id ASC
```

The results I get are confusing...the top row returned is by an author called `lewis lewis` and `lewis c s` ranks below this!

Now I have edited my `noiseENG.txt`, removed the single letters and rebuilt my fulltext catalogue but I see no change in my results. I know changing this file is working because I've added `lewis` to the list and it filtered out all searches with `lewis` in the author column.

Note: If I search for just 'c s' I get no results, so it seems like single letters are being ignored all together! Also, the fields indexed are all set to `British English`.

Does anyone know why the `FREETEXTTABLE` command would still be filtering out single letters?

Answer (score 0):

Try a phrase search a la:

```
@author = '"lewis c s"'
```

Comment: This does nothing...I really don't know where to go from here, I'm at a complete dead end!